# PDFs in Safari - Can they be annotated (setting Preview as the default viewer)?

Tags: macos, mac, pdf, safari, annotations

Is it possible to annotate PDFs displayed in Safari browser (setting Preview as the default viewer)?

Comment: What do you mean? PDFs in Preview can be annotated. In Safari, they can't. What does setting Preview as the default viewer have to do with it, then?

Comment: if Adobe plugin is not used I hoped that the Preview plugin was used instead, and so be able to annotate

Comment: The default Safari PDF plugin is not the same as the whole Preview.app. While OS X's [PDF Kit](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/pdfkit.html) supports [annotations](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzFramework/Classes/PDFAnnotation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003860), Safari doesn't have the UI to actually create them.

Comment: Do you mean it is not possible because Safari use webkit? Isn't possible to force it to use a Preview plugin?

Comment: There is no Preview plug-in. You can always disable PDF support in Webkit by running the following command in Terminal: `defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitOmitPDFSupport -bool YES` Accessing a PDF in Safari will then just download it instead of displaying it in PDF. Safari is a *viewer*, so you cannot edit (and save) anything. It just doesn't fit with the rest of the behavior of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special "Preview plugin" for Safari.

Safari – just like Preview.app – uses [*PDF Kit*](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/pdfkit.html), an OS X framework, to display PDFs. However, Safari can not create annotations on these PDFs, as it just doesn't have the implementation for creating [annotations](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzFramework/Classes/PDFAnnotation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003860). Apple would have to re-program Safari to add these features and the necessary interface for Safari to edit PDF documents.

Or you'd need to use another plugin that actually provides this functionality (none that I know of).